# Error: [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

Hi I am trying to run a script to get information from all the datastores.

The code script I am running is giving an error:

> ```
> At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Scripts\test.ps1:125 char:2
> +     $allstoreinfo += $storeinfo
> +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
> ```

The script is a simple for loop:

```
$datastores = Get-Datastore
$allstoreinfo = @()

foreach($store in $datastores){

$storeinfo = "" | Select Name, FileSystem, Type, CapacityGB, FreeSpaceGB

$datastoreview = get-datastore -Name $store.Name | Get-View | select -ExpandProperty summary

$CapacityGB = [math]::round($datastoreview.Capacity/1GB,2)

$FreeSpaceGB = [math]::round($datastoreview.FreeSpace/1GB,2)

$ProvisionedGB = [math]::round(($datastoreview.Capacity - $datastoreview.FreeSpace + $datastoreview.Uncommitted)/1GB,2)
$storeinfo.Name = $store.Name

$storeinfo.FileSystem = $store.FilesystemVersion

$storeinfo.Type = $store.Type

$storeinfo.CapacityGB = $CapacityGB

$storeinfo.FreeSpaceGB = $FreeSpaceGB

$allstoreinfo += $storeinfo

}

Write-Host "---------------------------------"

$allstoreinfo | Select Name, FileSystem, Type, CapacityGB, FreeSpaceGB

Write-Host "---------------------------------"
```

Comment: i don't see where you defined `$allstoreinfo`. that looks like you intend for it to be a standard array - so you should define it before trying to use it. ///// as an aside, using `+=` to add to a standard array is slow. once the number of items gets "large", each add takes MUCH longer. why? because the standard array has a fixed size - so all adds require copying to a new, one-item-larger array. the fix is to use a Generic.List instead. that has a working `.Add()` method. [*grin*]

Comment: Where the `$datastores` variable comes from? Please [edit] the question and complete the code to a [mcve].

Comment: This code works for me. Adding in the $allstoreinfo = @() fixed this issue.